# just change the vowel to the next letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

First I want to prove whether there is a vowel in the sentence, if there is a vowel is replaced by the next letter. Letters that are not vowels are not replaced but remain the same in the output.

The results of the coding that I made became inappropriate.

```
function changeVocals(str){
    var split = str.split('')
    var vocal = 'aiueo'
    var change = 'bjvfp'
    var a = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < vocal.length; j++) {
            if (vocal[j] === split[i]) {
                a = a + change
            } else {
                a = a + split[i]
            }
        }
    }
    return a     
}

console.log(changeVocals('Alexa')); //'Blfxb'
```

I expect the output of 'Alexa' to be 'Blfxb', but the actual output is the sentence appears to be repetitive.

Actual Output: AAAAAllllleeebjvfpexxxxxbjvfpaaaa

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object for mapping the values, and replace the matching value based on the case

```js
const mapper = {
  a: 'b', e: 'f', i: 'j', o: 'p', u: 'v',
  A: 'B', E: 'F', I: 'J', O: 'P', U: 'V'
}

const changeVocals = (string) => {
  return string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, match => mapper[match])
}
console.log(changeVocals('Alexa'));
```

Comment: This is a smart and concise approach to this problem. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `map`;

```js
var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
var text = 'Alexa';
var result = text.split('').map(x => vowels.indexOf(x.toLowerCase())>=0 ? String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt()+1) : x).join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeVocals(str){ 
return [...str].map(letter => "aeiouAEIOU".contains(letter) ? String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0)+1) : letter).join('');
}

changeVocals("Alexa");
```

But somehow, code snippet does not recognize `contains` function

Comment: Glad to help, if it is correct answer please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes I found in your attempt. I tried to fix that to make it working as you see below. But your attempt was really close. I hope my comments will help you to understand that 2 area where you made the mistakes.

```
function changeVocals(str) {
    var split = str.split('');
    var vocal = 'aiueo';
    var change = 'bjvfp';
    var a = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < vocal.length; j++) {
            // When there is a match we will not continue
            // so break out of the loop.
            if (vocal[j] === split[i]) {
                // this test if the match is lowercase to lowercase
                a = a + change[j];
                break;
            } else if (vocal[j].toUpperCase() === split[i]) {
                // this test if the match is uppercase to uppercase
                a = a + change[j].toUpperCase();
                break;
            }
        }
        // When there is no match found we just copy the input
        // character to the resulting string.
        // We figured there is no match found when we see
        // that the resulting string length is less than the current
        // value of i
        if (a.length < i + 1) a = a + split[i];
    }

    return a;
}

console.log(changeVocals('Alexa'));
//'Blfxb'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertot(string) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    const element = string[i];
    const isPresent = vowels.findIndex((f) => { return f === element.toLowerCase(); });
    if (isPresent !== -1) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(element.charCodeAt() + 1);
    } else {
      str += element;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

const text = 'Alexa';
const modified = convertot(text);
console.log(text);
console.log(modified);
```